# Symfony save an object of different model

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I have a model `Poster` and the server stores images. So the model has a `filename` field. I have a form class `MakenewForm.php` and I need to override its `doSave()` so as to achieve a save for a `Poster` object. the `MakenewForm` has a text field which is written over a preset image using `imagettftext`. so for saving, I need to

```
1. save the modified image data onto a file in the filesystem. 
2. save an object of Poster class with filename field set to the newly saved file
```

For step 1, I want to get a random name for the new file. I know that symfony uses random file naming for uploaded files(`file input widget and file validator`), I would like to use the same function but I can't find out which it is.

For step 2, I'm a bit confused due to this `$con` variable. What is its use? and How do I use it to meet my needs? Well, I can always achieve saving by making an object of `PosterForm` and setting appropriate fields and calling `doSave` for it. But I'd like to override the default `doSave()` function of the form. My `MakenewForm` `extends` `PosterForm` :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: the function is `generateFilename` and it is in `sfValidatedFile.class.php` file ([source file](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/validator/sfValidatedFile.class.php), also look at this [forum post](http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/t/20181/))

Step 2: look at the [form documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/02-Form-Validation#chapter_02_file_upload), on file upload section, specially listing 2-20, where is show how to save a file from a form with a file name of choice